# how to add more hobbies to a person

Tags: java, file

I need to show more hobbies for a person from a file, and I don't know how to do that. What I need is something like this: `Stan Ilie : baschet, programare`

My code here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ListaHobby
{
    String line = "";
    Hobby h, h1;
    Persoana p;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    ArrayList<Persoana> listOfPersons;
    ArrayList<Hobby> listOfHobbies;

    public void writeListaHobbies()
    {
        try
        {
            listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Persoana>();
            FileReader file1 = new FileReader("Persoane.txt");

            listOfHobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
            FileReader file2 = new FileReader("Hobby.txt");

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file1);
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file2);
            String line1 = "";
            String line2 = "";

            while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line1.trim().contains("ID"))
                {
                    String[] attributes = line1.split(";"); // split it at every ";"

                    p = new Persoana(); // make a new person
                    p.setId(Integer.parseInt(attributes[0]));
                    p.setNume(attributes[1]);
                    p.setPrenume(attributes[2]);
                    p.setDataNasterii(attributes[3]);
                    p.setProfesie(attributes[4]);

                    listOfPersons.add(p);
                }
            }

            while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line2.trim().contains("ID"))
                {
                    String[] attributes = line2.split(";"); // split it at every ";"

                    h = new Hobby(); // make a new hobby
                    h.setId(Integer.parseInt(attributes[0]));
                    h.setNume(attributes[1]);
                    h.setDescriere(attributes[2]);
                    h.setNrPers(Integer.parseInt(attributes[3]));
                    h.setElemNecesar(attributes[4]);

                    listOfHobbies.add(h);
                }
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("PersHobby.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for (Persoana p : listOfPersons)
            {
                for (Hobby h : listOfHobbies)
                {
                    String s = p.getNume() + " " + p.getPrenume() + ": ";

                    String s1 = h.getNume();

                    System.out.print(s);
                    System.out.println(s1);

                    bw.write(s);
                    bw.append(s1);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            }

            bw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

and my output is this:

```
  Stan Ilie: baschet
  Stan Ilie: fotbal
  Stan Ilie: chitara
  Stan Ilie: pianul
  Stan Ilie: programarea
  Becali GG: baschet
  Becali GG: fotbal
  Becali GG: chitara
  Becali GG: pianul
  Becali GG: programarea .....
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: yes,i need to do this until tomorrow

Comment: thanks,now i know what i have to do in the future.

Comment: @Bernard  Yes 'homework' - tagged now.  Good call.

Comment: so basically what you need is a new hobby like "chess" or "reading" or whatever? how many hobbies are there in your hobbies.txt file ?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is tagged as homework, i don't want to give you the solution but i give you a hint:

the problem is you write a line to the output file every time you read a hobby.
You have to create a string which contains all the hobbies relative to a person, and then you can write this string to the file.

Pseudocode:

```
foreach Person p {
   String currentPerson = p.getNume() + " " + p.getPrenume() + ": ";

   foreach Hobby h {
      currentPerson += h.getNume() + ",";
   }

   Write currentPerson to file and print currentPerson to console
}
```